# Generate n numbers in ascending order with their sum equal to m and difference between adjacent numbers increases by a constant number, in Python

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to generate `n numbers` from `0 to m` in such a way that all numbers are in ascending order and the difference between two adjacent numbers also increases (*by a constant number*) as we move towards the last numbers,

For example, if I want to generate 3 numbers (`n = 3`) to the value of `m = 10`, then,

```
arr = [2, 3, 5]
```

That is:

- All numbers of array are in ascending order
- Their sum is equal to the number `m`
- The difference between the adjacent numbers is increasing as we move towards the end.
- The difference increases by a constant number (e.g. in this particular case, it increases by 1, i.e., *3 - 2 = 1 and then 5 - 3 = 1+1*)

Another example could be, if the value of `n = 5` and `m = 250`, then the expected output would be:

```
arr = [10, 20, 40, 70, 110]
```

**There can be multiple answers to one case.**

What formula can be used to attain such a thing for any given value of `n` and `m` *(Say I want 100 numbers from 0 to 80000, how would I generate them in the sequence required?)*

Comment: Hint. Your numbers will satisfy a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c$. Use the conditions to try to determine $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I'd suggest looking up *arithmetic sequences* and *arithmetic series*.

Answer (score 1):

Let the first number be $a$, the difference between the first and second $d$, and the increase in difference between (third-second) and (second-first) be $k$.  Then the numbers are
$$a,a+d,a+2d+k, a+3d+3k, a+4d+6k, \ldots$$
We let $T_p=\frac 12p(p+1)$ be the $p^{th}$ [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), the sum of all the numbers from $1$ to $p$.
After $n$ terms the sum is $$na +T_{n-1}d+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}T_ik\\
=na+\frac d2n(n-1)+k\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac i2+\frac {i^2}2\\
=na+\frac d2n(n-1)+\frac k6(n-2)(n-1)n$$
so choose $a,d,k$ to make this equal to $m$.  If you choose $n,d,k$ first you can find $a$ by division, but it may not come out without a remainder.

Comment: @DavidK:  Thank you.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you choose the starting number to be some number $k$, and the difference to be $d$. Then, the sum of the $n$ numbers will be:
$$k+(k+T_1d)+(k+T_2d)+\cdots+(k+T_{n-1}d)=nk+\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}6d$$
where $T_i$ is the $i$'th triangular number.

Expanded, this would be:
$$nk+\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}6d=nk+\frac{dn^3-dn}6=\frac d6n^3+\left(k-\frac d6\right)n$$
This sum is equal to $m$, so we have the equation:
$$\frac d6n^3+\left(k-\frac d6\right)n=m$$
There could be multiple choices for $k$ and $d$ at this point, but to simplify the calculations, we can choose $k=d/6$:
$$\frac d6n^3=m\implies d=\frac{6m}{n^3}$$
Which means $$k=\frac m{n^3}$$
(Note that $k$ and $d$ are not guaranteed to be integers.)

#### Example

Let's take $n=5$ and $m=250$.

We get:
$$d=\frac{6m}{n^3}=\frac{1500}{125}=12$$
So:
$$k=\frac d6=\frac{12}6=2$$
Which means that the numbers generated are:
$$k,k+d,k+3d,k+6d,k+10d\implies2,14,38,74,122$$
To confirm the answer, we can first take the consecutive difference, which gives:
$$12,24,36,48$$
We can see that the difference between each consecutive term is increasing by $d=12$ each time, as expected.

Now let's take the sum of all the terms:
$$2+14+38+74+122=250$$
$m=250$ so this is correct.

---

Here is some example python code which generates the $n$ numbers based on what we did above (takes in $n$ and $m$ as space separated integers): [code](https://tio.run/##FY3NCsIwEITv@xRzTGqxorRIwSeRHgLxJyTZLjEefPq4YQ4zHzMw8qvvnS9XKa3xiIwbshMTuI6B5VuNPX4kBXVLXstlyJPhQWUpKvtpIUoa7hu5zvTcCwICozh@PQzblZBw0EXcCLEnR3DdPZEUvTLJtjbjPJ/@)

Comment: Should be $k+(k+d)+(k+3d)+(k+6d)+\cdots$

Comment: @DanielMathias Oh whoops I read the problem wrong, lemme see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @DanielMathias Does this look correct now?

Comment: I think you should find $k$ as a function of $d$, with $1 \le d < \frac{6m}{n^3-n}$

Comment: @DanielMathias So you mean solving for $k$ in terms of $d,n,m$? Also what's wrong with choosing a specific value of $k$?

Comment: By fixing the ratio $k/d$ you reduce the generality of the answer. Among other things, you can't use your result to find integer solutions in the case where your arbitrary choice results in a non-integer solution.

Comment: @DavidK Ok well I will see what I can do, no guarantees though

Comment: The problem I have is that I found the function for $k$, but I'm not sure about the conditions needed in order for both $k$ and $d$ to be integers.